# Thematic Map - Forced Scale

Tags: r, tmap

Trying to create a thematic map to represent data on a LargeSpatialPolygonDataFrame and I'm having difficulty creating a forced scale.

I'd like to make the following scale: seq(0,4500,500) to create ten different fill categories regardless of if the data frame has data in that range or not like the following image.

[image]

Texas_LMA SpatialPolygonDataFrame:

```
> Texas_LMA  
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 33 
extent      : -106.6278, -93.52764, 25.85646, 36.5004  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 10
names       : LMA, Sol_index, Capacity, LMA.data,     Technology, Water_Capacity_Value, Robust.,  X, Water_Capacity, Water_Capacity_String 
min values  :   1,       135,       21,        1,        Biomass,                 0.00,       1, NA,              0,                    0% 
max values  :  33,       135,     1739,       32, Biomass | Wind,                 0.84,       1, NA,             84,                   84%
```

Has the following Capacity ranges

```
> unique(Texas_LMA$Capacity)
[1]  892 1739  156   NA   21  495
```

I'm using tmap to create the thematic map with the following code:

```
Fixed_Capacity_Heatmap <- tm_shape(Texas_LMA)+
  tm_fill("Capacity",style="fixed",breaks=seq(0,4500,500))+
  tm_borders()
```

Results of the plot when there aren't enough categories [Capacity Plot with 5 categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OER09.png)

[image]

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Which `tmap` version are you working with and can you provide your data?

Comment: I managed to get close to what I wanted by building it a layer at a time.

I check if the capacity was under a certain threshold and applied a palette value that matches the first plot. I'll look into why it wasn't working with the standard tmap on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should have been fixed as of https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/commit/3a33563a4336042307320f470dc8189fb0572477, i.e. CRAN version 1.4-1. The problem was that `classInt` was struggling with numeric variables with only a few unique values. Please let me know if it still doesn't work, preferably with a reproducible example.